# TFS Build Fail The tag 'Chart' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, tfs, tfsbuild

I have a C# WPF solution that builds just fine on my Windows 7 Box running VS 2017.

We are moving to automated builds on a TFS build server.

Now I get a few errors such as

> Error MC3074: The tag 'Chart' does not exist in XML namespace
>   'clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit'

and

> Error MC3074: The tag 'StockChart' does not exist in XML namespace
>   'http://schemas.amcharts.com/stock/wpf/2009/xaml'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok I misspoke.  I have a Windows 7 Box running VS 2017

Comment: If something is found wrong in the question it can be edited. Putting error messages as quotes improves readability. For linebreak is necessary to use double enter or <br>.

Comment: Are you using XAML build or vNext build? And have you tried to remote to the build server and build directly on the server side locally, this will narrow down if the issue is related to your test environment.